# Why is "colorize" not working on fully opaque parts in Krita?

Tags: color, filter, krita

I'm trying to colorize a layer with the HSV/HSL Adjustment filter shown below:

[image: Getting started with Krita - HSV/HSL Adjustment]

However, I noticed that the colorization would likely work only on fully opaque parts. I tried to colorize a tree, but some leaves won't:

[image: Bad leave colorization]

Is there an explanation about this phenomenon?

---

Note: the first picture came from *[Getting started with Krita](https://www.davidrevoy.com/article186/tutorial-getting-started-with-krita-2-3-colorize) (2/3)* by David Revoy - CC BY 4.0

Comment: I think it could be possible the color is black or dark enough that you can't see a difference. I haven't used Krita, but I would assume it works the same as in Photoshop. You can't colorize black or white, even if it's translucent. So **if I'm not totally wrong, you need to probably increase `Lightness` (move it to the right) a little bit to see the color change**. And to not ruin anything, you might have to select the problem section before doing this so you don't make other parts too light (or not).

Comment: Maybe "Colorize not working on dark translucent color in Krita" or maybe "Why is colorize not working in Krita". I think it's probably fine is the title is a bit vague in this case. There aren't that many reasons for it not to work. I think the title, as it is now is fine too...

Comment: Well then... You super sure? Like no matter how much you add lightness, it won't get colorized? What if you merge the translucent image to a white background? Would the color change then?

Comment: I think you should post the answer yourself. It'll be some hours before the site let's you accept it, but you will be able to make a better answer since you know better what worked for you.

Comment: No, it's fine. You know more about it now than I do. Go for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Joonas' help (and from a nice user in the Krita official IRC channel), I realized those areas were actually *fully* black. It wasn't noticeable since a transparent black pixel could look like a lighter one.

One approach to solve that was to set a background layer fitting the tree shape through a transparency mask.